# deserlize json file with coordinates to C# classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've a json file with coordinates [x,y]
I would like to do query based on the coordinates but i did not know how to transfer this to c# classes.
I tried using https://json2csharp.com/ but it gives me the classes like this

```cs
public class DatasetData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int channel_id { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int speed_1 { get; set; }
    public int speed_2 { get; set; }
    public int speed_3 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<DatasetData> dataset_data { get; set; }
}
```

This is the json. As you see I've inside the location; type and coordinates but i don't know to extract them to classes and using them.

```json
{
   "dataset_data":[
      {
         "id":1234,
         "channel_id":2,
         "location":"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-1.17273271,51.9132423]}",
         "speed_1":1,
         "speed_2":2,
         "speed_3":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Deserialize the location property again, it's JSON as well.

Comment: can you please explain how ?

Comment: Create a type like `class Location { public string Type { get; set; } public List<double> Coordinates { get; set; } }`, then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(root.Location)`.

Comment: Could you please provide a **valid** sample json?

Comment: @PeterCsala i've edited my json sample. can you check now plz

Comment: Are you getting this json response from some external api?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've followed your steps and it shows an error "Error converting value "{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.17273271,51.9132423]}" to type 'MyProject.Data.Traffic+Location"

Comment: @FadiAkkad Which json library are you using? Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json or ??

Comment: @afrose yes that's correct

Comment: @PeterCsala yes I'm using Newtonsoft

Comment: If you had this json response :
`{
  "dataset_data": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "channel_id": 2,
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -1.17273271, 51.9132423 ]
      },
      "speed_1": 1,
      "speed_2": 2,
      "speed_3": 3
    }
  ]
}`
then maybe mapping to the class would have been easier.

Comment: @afrose yes I agree with you but the thing is that the this response coming form external API.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? If you deserialized the JSON into a `root` variable of type `Root`, what happens if you try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(root.dataset_data[0].location)` ?

Comment: Thanks all.. It works finally. I've to do two deserializations as Peter and Lasse suggested,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your json is that the `location` is not an object rather than a string. So, you need to deserialize that as well.

If you define your `Location` class as [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) suggested:

```
public class Location
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Then all you need to do is to modify your `DatasetData` class like this:

```
public class DatasetData
{
    ...
    public string location { set; private get;}
    public Location Location => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(location);
    ...
}
```

- The `location` property is write only from the deserialization perspective
- The `Location` property is read only from the deserialization perspective